# Consecutive -not parallel- QgsTask execution in QgsTaskManager

Tags: pyqgis

**Situation:** I am working on a PyQGIS plugin that sends a multiple WPS request (https requests) from a `QgsTask` object to a server. In order to avoid freezing of the GUI for long requests I am using QgsTasks for the communication with the server. Due to limitations on the server side, I would like to let the `QgsTaskManager` work the list of tasks (eg. requests) **consecutively** (eg. one task at a time, no parallel execution).

**Question:** Is there any way to achieve the consecutive execution of `QgsTasks` with the `QgsTaskManager`using current PyQGIS API (3.12)? I thought about preparing the tasks in a list beforehand and then adding them one by one using a `for` loop or adding the main parent task.

**My solution approach so far:** I tried to manage this by using nested subtasks using `ParentDependsOnSubTask`. I thought about preparing the tasks in a list beforehand and then adding them one by one to the `QgsTaskManager`using a `for` loop. For testing I am using the example script for `QgsTask`at the [QGIS documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/tasks.html). I provide the adapted code for reference here:

```
import random
from time import sleep

from qgis.core import (
    QgsApplication, QgsTask, QgsMessageLog,
    )

MESSAGE_CATEGORY = 'RandomIntegerSumTask'

class RandomIntegerSumTask(QgsTask):
    """This shows how to subclass QgsTask"""
    def __init__(self, description, duration):
        super().__init__(description, QgsTask.CanCancel)
        self.duration = duration
        self.total = 0
        self.iterations = 0
        self.exception = None
    def run(self):
        """Here you implement your heavy lifting.
        Should periodically test for isCanceled() to gracefully
        abort.
        This method MUST return True or False.
        Raising exceptions will crash QGIS, so we handle them
        internally and raise them in self.finished
        """
        QgsMessageLog.logMessage('Started task "{}"'.format(
                                     self.description()),
                                 MESSAGE_CATEGORY, Qgis.Info)
        wait_time = self.duration / 100
        for i in range(100):
            sleep(wait_time)
            # use setProgress to report progress
            self.setProgress(i)
            arandominteger = random.randint(0, 500)
            self.total += arandominteger
            self.iterations += 1
            # check isCanceled() to handle cancellation
            if self.isCanceled():
                return False
            # simulate exceptions to show how to abort task
            if arandominteger == 42:
                # DO NOT raise Exception('bad value!')
                # this would crash QGIS
                self.exception = Exception('bad value!')
                return False
        return True
    def finished(self, result):
        """
        This function is automatically called when the task has
        completed (successfully or not).
        You implement finished() to do whatever follow-up stuff
        should happen after the task is complete.
        finished is always called from the main thread, so it's safe
        to do GUI operations and raise Python exceptions here.
        result is the return value from self.run.
        """
        if result:
            QgsMessageLog.logMessage(
                'Task "{name}" completed\n' \
                'Total: {total} (with {iterations} '\
              'iterations)'.format(
                  name=self.description(),
                  total=self.total,
                  iterations=self.iterations),
              MESSAGE_CATEGORY, Qgis.Success)
        else:
            if self.exception is None:
                QgsMessageLog.logMessage(
                    'Task "{name}" not successful but without '\
                    'exception (probably the task was manually '\
                    'canceled by the user)'.format(
                        name=self.description()),
                    MESSAGE_CATEGORY, Qgis.Warning)
            else:
                QgsMessageLog.logMessage(
                    'Task "{name}" Exception: {exception}'.format(
                        name=self.description(),
                        exception=self.exception),
                    MESSAGE_CATEGORY, Qgis.Critical)
                raise self.exception
    def cancel(self):
        QgsMessageLog.logMessage(
            'Task "{name}" was canceled'.format(
                name=self.description()),
            MESSAGE_CATEGORY, Qgis.Info)
        super().cancel()


task0 = RandomIntegerSumTask('Task 0', 5)
task1 = RandomIntegerSumTask('Task 1', 5)
task2 = RandomIntegerSumTask('Task 2', 5)
task3 = RandomIntegerSumTask('Task 3', 5)

tasklist = [task0,task1,task2,task3]
#len=4
for i, task in enumerate(tasklist):
    if i < len(tasklist)-1:
        print(tasklist[i].description())
        print("subtask {}, dependent on {}".format(tasklist[i+1].description(), tasklist[i+1:]))
        task.addSubTask(tasklist[i+1], tasklist[i+1:], QgsTask.ParentDependsOnSubTask)
        tasklist[i] = task
        print(tasklist[i].description())

#start with the last task that all others are dependending on
tasklist.reverse()

QgsApplication.taskManager().addTask(tasklist[0])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some [research](https://forum.qt.io/topic/84686/waiting-for-qthreads-to-finish/7)  on the `QThread` class and possible strategies for handling consecutive execution of those thread objects (which are similar to `QgsTask`), I found a solution to the problem:

For starting `QgsTasks` consecutively, don't use a for loop that adds them to the `QgsTaskManager` and don't use any preparation of the task objects (eg. subtasks, dependencies, etc.). As a description of the solution, I post the pseudo-code here (it is just for transporting the concept):

```
self.task_step = 0
self.tasklist = [task0,task1,task2,task3]    

def startFirstComputationStep(self):
        #connect the tasks taskCompleted signal to a function that starts the next step
        for i, task in enumerate(self.tasklist):
            task.taskCompleted.connect(self.startNextComputationStep)
            #replace tasks
            self.tasklist[i](task)

        #kick off computation by starting the first task
        QgsApplication.taskManager().addTask(self.tasklist[self.task_step])
        #advance step once
        self.task_step = self.task_step + 1
        #if task emits finished, startNextComputationStep() is called


def startNextComputationStep(self):
    computation_task_cnt = len(self.tasklist)
    if self.task_step < computation_task_cnt:
        QgsApplication.taskManager().addTask(self.tasklist[self.task_step])
        self.task_step = self.task_step + 1
    else:
        print("Computation of all steps finished")
        self.task_step = 0 #reset to 0 if finished
```

Instead of bulk-loading all tasks to `QgsTaskManager`, implement two method such as `startFirstComputationStep()` and `startNextComputationStep` in the class managing your tasks. Connect all your tasks `taskCompleted` signals from your `tasks` in the `tasklist` to start the `startNextComputationStep()`. Meanwhile keep track of which task is currently executed by storing it in a member variable (`task_step` in the example). The first time the `startNextComputationStep()` is called, after the first task is finished, kicking off the consecutive execution of the `QgsTasks`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work as well. Using the addSubTask method, add subtasks to the first task and create dependencies. The downside is: only the main task is shown in TaskManager, meaning tasks can't be canceled individually.

With this code, tasks are executed in order 1 2 3 0.

```
"""Preparing QgsTasks:"""
# tasklist
tasklist = [task0,task1,task2,task3]
# add all tasks, except first, recursevly as subtask to first task
subtasks = []
for i in range(1, len(tasklist)):
    tasklist[0].addSubTask(tasklist[i], subtasks, QgsTask.ParentDependsOnSubTask)
    subtasks.append(tasklist[i])
# pass only the first task to the taskManager
QgsApplication.taskManager().addTask(tasklist[0])
```

With this code, they will be executed in order 0 1 2 3:

```
"""Preparing QgsTasks:"""
# tasklist
tasklist = [task0,task1,task2,task3]
# add all tasks, except last task, recursevly as subtask to last task
subtasks = []
for i in range(0, len(tasklist)):
    tasklist[len(tasklist)-1].addSubTask(tasklist[i], subtasks, QgsTask.ParentDependsOnSubTask)
    subtasks.append(tasklist[i])
# pass only the last task to the taskManager
QgsApplication.taskManager().addTask(tasklist[len(tasklist)-1])
```